# How do I select edges where the vertices share a common property?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, gremlin

I'd like to filter edges by comparing one property of each edge's vertices. This is the Gremlin code I hoped would return all edges where the vertices have the same `GROUP_NAME` as one another:

```
g.E.filter{it.outV.GROUP_NAME == it.inV.GROUP_NAME}
```

It doesn't return any results. What have I missed? Thanks.

UPDATE:

This is one solution that handles the direct comparison, but I'd like to be able to do different comparisons in addition to equality.

```
g.E.filter{it.bothV.GROUP_NAME.dedup().count() == 1}.count()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is that you need to break the values out of the pipes. There are a [couple methods](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Gremlin-Methods) to do that, but I'd use `next()`.

```
g.E.filter{it.outV.name.next() == it.inV.name.next()}
```

Obviously, you could use other comparisons there as well.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Learning more about how pipes work is my next priority.